# Calculating the missing dimension?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area, volume, foundations

1) a right cone has a surface area 12 m${^2}$ and radius 1.3 m

**here is my answers:**

1) $s$ = 1.28

[(photo of how i got my answer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ovb.jpg)

**textbook answer:** 1.64 m

how did they get that??

Comment: Hmm... I got $1.28$  as well

Comment: You have accepted an incorrect answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The formula to calculate the surface area of a cone is:

$$SA=\pi r(r+\sqrt{h^2+r^2})$$

We know the $SA$ and $r$. Now solve for $h$.

$$12=\pi(1.3)(1.3+\sqrt{h^2+(1.3)^2})$$

$$\frac{12}{1.3\pi}-1.3=\sqrt{h^2+(1.3)^2}\text{ moved stuff we already know to left side}$$

$$(\frac{12}{1.3\pi}-1.3)^2=h^2\text{ squared both sides}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{12}{1.3\pi}-1.3}=h\text{ take square root to solve for $h$}$$

$h\approx 1.28$

I'm guessing they made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in thinking that they want the vertical height of the cone. For a cone, $s$ usually represents the slant height. So the first thing you want to is to express the total surface are as

$$S=\pi r s+\pi r^2$$

where $\pi r s$ is the lateral area. Then

$$
s=\frac{S-\pi r^2}{\pi r}\approx1.638
$$

as in your text!